# I can't manage to get to scroll down in Selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, webdriver

I am trying to scroll down the page because the help element overlaps the next page button after I click the button once because the pages moves down.
The next button is above the match history table.
I tried using

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

nothing is happening,
then I tried using

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='Table flx-sm dir-r-sm jst-s-sm flx-nw-sm ialgn-st-sm']")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

it gives me the error: `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: (1009, 835) is out of bounds of viewport width (1536) and height (750)`

I tried using

```
html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
html.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Nothing is moving still.This is the code and the website that I am trying it on.(I also tried using Chrome but I had the same result)

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url2="https://app.senpai.gg/lol/profile/eune/Primm"
driver.get(url2)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/section/div/section/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/button[2]')
    time.sleep(10)
while true:
    if(button.is_enabled() and button.is_displayed()):
        button.click();
    else:
        break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('[class="el-main"]').scrollBy(0,$('[class="el-main"]').scrollHeight)
```

you have to find the scroll element and then use scrolBY on that

```
driver.execute_script("$('[class=\"el-main\"]').scrollBy(0,$('[class=\"el-main\"]').scrollHeight);")
```

if you get $ not defined use:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0,arguments[0].scrollHeight);", driver.find_element_by_class_name('el-main'))
```

**You can also do:**

```
driver.get(url2)

driver.find_element_by_class_name('el-main').click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body").send_keys(Keys.END)
```

FIrst you have to bring scroll to focus by clicking it and then send END key on body

**finding locator:**

[image]